# Pyspark Dataframe Case expression

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a case expression for a column based on the values of a different column comparing it to a list. this is what I have so far.
First I made a list looks like this when I print it

```
partner = [u'AFLK', u'BLCK', u'MACH']
```

Then I have a dataframe with name 'joined_df' with columns a,b,c,bike_cd,geo all strings.

Now I want to make some transformations on this dataframe. This is what I have so far. I am trying to write a case statement to populate the column 'geo' based on the values of column bike_cd. If a record has a bike_cd that appears in the list 'partner', I want geo of the record to be 'GLOBAL' otherwise it should default to whatever the value is there in 'geo' column.

```
final_df = joined_df.select(joined_df.a,
joined_df.b,
joined_df.c,
joined_df.bike_cd,
("joined_df.geo", expr ("CASE WHEN joined_df.{0} IN {1} THEN 'GLOBAL' ELSE joined_df.geo END".format(bike_cd,partner))),)
```

I tried a few thing but nothing worked. Now I see the following error with the above code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
NameError: name 'bike_cd' is not defined
```

Alternaltely I tried this, it works but I am getting an extra column instead changing the existing column geo.

```
final_df = joined_df.select('*', when(joined_df.bike_cd.isin(partner), 'GLOBAL').otherwise(joined_df.geo))
```

I am not sure if I got the right idea or this could be totally wrong. I appreciate your help.

> Blockquote

Comment: Can you give some sample data?

Comment: seems like `bike_cd` in the format should be string lateral instead of variable, no?

Comment: @LiorChaga if I do this

`("joined_df.geo", expr ("CASE WHEN joined_df.bike_cd IN {0} THEN 'GLOBAL' ELSE joined_df.geo END".format(partner))),)`

the error would be

`pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nmismatched input 'joined_df' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 10)\n\n== SQL ==\nCASE WHEN joined_df.bike_cd IN [u'AFLK', u'BLCK',u'MACH',] THEN 'GLOBAL' ELSE joined_df.geo END\n----------^^^\n"`

Comment: Change your expr to `f"""CASE WHEN joined_df.bike_cd IN ('{"','".join(partner)}') THEN 'GLOBAL' ELSE joined_df.geo END"""` , currently you are passing a list for `IN` which it doesnot understand: `[` vs `(`

Comment: @anky hey, thanks for your reply but I couldn't follow what you did there. I executed the same but getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at END """))) after the triple quotes.

Comment: @anky I tried this ```final_df = joined_df.select('*', when(joined_df.bike_cd.isin(partner), 'GLOBAL').otherwise(joined_df.geo))``` It works but it adds a new column instead of changing the existing column geo. Any easy way to fix it?

Comment: @ndev instead of using select you can use `withColumn` : `joined_df = joined_df.withColumn("geo",when(joined_df.bike_cd.isin(partner), 'GLOBAL').otherwise(joined_df.geo))`